# build a css frame all around content

Tags: css

i need to build a frame all around mi contents that would scroll under the frame

i made a top margin a bottom and a left and right margin

it seems to work correctlly but some times between bottom and middle or top and middle i get a void pixel

and on mobile device, without viewport set it get a little worst

i don't have other idea on how make the same thing in a better way

here an example link
http://jsfiddle.net/zBAPX/

```
#mask-center-container {
 z-index: 1000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 10%;
 bottom: 4%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mask-center-container-sx {
 height: 100%;
 width: 21%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mask-center-container-ce {
 height: 100%;
 width: 56%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mask-center-container-dx {
 height: 100%;
 width: 22%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mask-top {
 z-index: 3000;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;  
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mask-bottom {
 z-index: 3000;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;  
 height: 4%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey there...this is roughly 10 times the amount of code you actually need to accomplish what you have so far. What are you trying to do exactly? Scrollbars in the viewport you've created?

Comment: i need a window (a hole) inside an alpha overlay that cover all my browser page, but i need to click on link and elements that are behind it, like this but the windows should be transparent [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew4kJ/) in this case even if i would find a solution to make the window transparent i guess it would be not possible to click through

Answer (score 0):

I only know of one way to effectively click 'through' an element, and that is to use the experimental `pointer-events` property. Here's a writeup from CSS Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

One major flaw: no IE support prior to IE11.